# Determine the amount of points needed to convert an arc to line segments

Tags: c++, geometry

The arc is defined by start_point, sweeping_angle, and center_point. If given a parameter "tolerance", which is the error between original arc and line segments. How do I calculate the minimum amount of points needed to convert this arc into line segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest deviance between small arc of angle theta and its chord is at the middle, and value of this deviance is  ([versine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine))

```
tol = R * (1-Cos(theta/2))
```

Having N arcs

```
SweepAngle = N * theta
theta = SweepAngle / N
tol = R * (1-Cos(SweepAngle / (2N)))
tol/R = (1-Cos(SweepAngle / (2N)))
Cos(SweepAngle / (2N)) = 1 - tol/R 
SweepAngle / (2N) = ArcCos(1 - tol/R )

N = 1/2 * SweepAngle / ArcCos(1 - tol/R )
```

Quick check:

```
SweepAngle = Pi
R = 1
tol = 1 - sqrt(2)/2 ~ 0.293
N = Pi/2 / ArcCos(0.707) = (Pi/2) / (Pi/4) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! That helps a lot